# Import Project using pom.xml

Tags: maven-2

Is there any way to point ecilpse (Galileo) at a pom.xml file located at a URL and have it setup my workspace based upon what is in the pom.xml file.  I have tried to use the import maven project feature in eclipse by downloading the pom.xml file to my desktop and importing the pom.xml file.  That resulted in my project containing all of the items from my desktop.

There was also a function to Checkout Maven Project from SVN and I tried that also, but encountered the following error:

> Can't rename c:\users\leto\FunJavaDevelopment\maven.1250263290804

The SVN URL is http://dbunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dbunit/trunk

Am I just misunderstanding how to use the pom.xml file? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, I'm posting this on stackoverflow rather than dbunits site because I thought others might find the answer to be informative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up the scm section of the POM, you can do **Import...**->**Maven**->**Materialize Maven Projects**, then enter the groupId or artifactId of the project you want to import.

If the project is a dependency of one of your existing workspace projects you can also right-click on it and then select **Maven**->**Import Project**.

If m2eclipse can find a version of the project in the index for any repository it will list it, and you can then import the project.

For details of the scm section of the POM you need to see the documentation for your [SCM provider](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/index.html). For example here's the [SVN provider](http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html) documentation.

There's more detail on importing projects in the [m2eclipse book](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Importing+Maven+projects). It also describes how to import local file system Maven projects.

Here's an example of the Maven import wizard in action:

[alt text http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/73335/import-projects-poms.png](http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/73335/import-projects-poms.png)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the error with renaming the folder is caused by the Windows file indexing. I am still seeing this when I use Indigo on Windows 7 (other OS don't have the locking problem). Turning off the file indexing for the workspace folder seems to fix it.

To do this, find the workspace folder in Windows Explorer (it defaults to C:\Users\$USERNAME$\workspace), then open the properties for that folder, click on "Advanced" and de-select "Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in addition to file properties". Confirm the dialog and make sure it applies the change to all folders and files inside the changed one. Afterwards you should not see the problem any more.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Import Projects feature is only in the latest stable development build of the m2e plugin.

Here's the easiest way I've found to do what you are describing:

1. Check out the entire svn repo somewhere, including all of the source (I use TortoiseSVN for this)
   Go to File...Import..Maven..Existing Maven Projects
2. Browse to the directory I just checked out, and click "Finish"
3. If there are multiple nested modules, the m2e plugin will create a new project for each one, in addition to one master project that contains all of the projects, but isn't a Java project.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old thread, I thought I'd share my solution to the "Can't rename..." error:

- Make sure you don't have another project with the same name in c:\users\leto\FunJavaDevelopment\, e.g. a previous version of dbunit. Maven won't override the old project, it just gives this cryptic error.
- Make sure no other programs are reading files within c:\users\leto\FunJavaDevelopment\maven.1250263290804. For instance, if you had a command prompt cd'd to this directory, it would block the rename.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because something is blocking your project and you must delete all your old dependencies and folders. Something is blocking and the project is bad deleted.  In my case cywing was the guilty.

1. Go explorer and delete the folder maven.1250263290804
2. Close all folders / cmd / cywing.

Try again! It Works!!